# Avahi (zeroconf/bonjour) service in bridged VirtualBox sometimes not found outside host

Tags: firewall, virtualbox, avahi, mdns

I have a VirtualBox with Debian 3.2.51 guest (`vcube`) on Ubuntu 13.10 host (`ring`) with a bridged network adapter.
`vcube` has an Avahi service configured with a `vcube.local` name.

I can see/ping/access `vcube.local` by Bonjour name, but cannot see it from other hosts on the (wireless) network. At the same time, there's a lot of wire- and wirelessly connected hosts on the network that we happily see in `avahi-discover` or other Zeroconf clients.

I have no access to our router and cannot know if it's blocking mDNS or not.

In `iptables -vnL` output, there are no entries, policies are ACCEPT and byte counts are 0 both on `vcube` and `ring`.

The same discovery problem happens for a copy of `vcube` VirtualBox on a totally different network.

Sometimes it just starts working - we suspect this happens when we start ANOTHER copy of `vcube` on a different host.

How do I diagnose or fix this problem?

Comment: Are you able to ping the guest Debian OS by ip address from one of wireless devices?

Comment: Something is blocking multicast UDP. You should run a packet dump (I suggest `tshark`, but `tcpdump` will do) in various places: 1. inside vcube on (`-i`) its virtual network adapter; 2. on ring, on the virtual adapter bridged to vcube; 3. on ring, on the physical network adapter (eth0 or such); 4. on another host on the network. You are looking for the mDNS packets, to see where they are blocked. To recap: `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 'host 224.0.0.251 and port 5353'` replacing eth0 as appropriate.

Comment: @Tim, yes, it responds to IP address, but not to avahi name.

Comment: Thanks @Tobia, will try it tomorrow. I believe this must be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your problem very well but I know bridge interfaces and UDP multicasst/boradcast can trigger some eratics behaviours.
To work it around you may want to disable multicast snooping on the bridge interface:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/net/$IFACE/bridge/multicast_snooping
```

Though I don't know virtualbox well enough to to be sure it uses proper linux bridge utils to setup bridge  adpaters...

Comment: Looks like this indeed is a problam with multicast (IGMP) snooping in Linux (http://troglobit.com/blog/2013/07/09/multicast-howto/). I wasn't able to fix it with this recipe http://shlrm.org/blog/2013/04/18/multicast-snooping-is-bad/ , because I don't have a `bridge` dir in my `/sys/devices/virtual/net/vboxnet0/` on Linux 3.11.0-15. Stuck again, but at least now I know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I could *NOT* get to work these two guys:

- `avahi-daemon - The Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon`
- `iptables — administration tool for IPv4 packet filtering and NAT`

I even followed following:
[Well known TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629). *MAYBE* you'll have better luck then me)

Comment: It used t work for me, without `iptables` though. Just stopped at some point. Reproduced twice in a totally different environments, only Virtualbox image was the same.